# GitHub Copilot menu options not showing up in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022, github-copilot

I've installed GitHub CoPilot and GitHub Copilot Chat in Visual Studio 2022 (17.7.4).
I see the GitHub Copilot icon at the bottom let of my code windows, but no Copilot specific menu options when I right click on any line in the C# file, and without that I don't know how to get started.
My goal is to generate documentation for C# classes/methods by asking Copilot Chat questions like "what does this method do" like I see in the demo videos:

[image]

I see the GitHub Copilot icon at the bottom left of my code windows (red square highlight), but no Copilot specific menu options when I right click on any line in the C# file, and without that I don't know how to get started.

Comment: **SAME ISSUE Note:** Copilot's code completion works totally fine (unless it does, ahem, _even better_ than totally fine), but View > GitHub Copilot Chat is absent. I'm at the latest a.t.m. VS2022 version 17.9.3 and have all extensions auto-updated regularly. I haven't seen the menu item ever.The only thing than _may possibly_ set me apart is that my Copilot has been given to me free of charge for being a large public project maintainer; it sounds rather implausible, altho', as, IIUIC, I've been afforded the most useful function of it.

Answer (score 0):

After installing Copilot Chat extension followed by View > GitHub Copilot Chat the 'Ask Copilot' menu command showed in the right click C# code editor menu.

Answer (score 0):

I just opened Option > Edit > Keyboard and entered `copilot` in the filer box. Lo and lo and behold, there were 10 commands. The naming pattern of the command is usual for those grouped under a sub-menu, as if they were supposed to be on a submenu of the menubar-level Edit menu, only they in fact aren't. Two of these are bound to accelerator keys in the default VS2022 keyboard scheme, both in the context of Text Editor:

- <kbd>Alt+Ctrl+Enter</kbd>, bound to `Edit.Copilot.Open`, opens the Copilot window, which you may dock as you please. I don't see a chat window there, only a list of contextual suggestions.
- <kbd>Alt+Ctrl+/</kbd> is bound to `Edit.Copilot.ToggleInlineSuggestion`, which is doing I have no idea what yet.

You may type some of there commands directly into the Command windows (View > Other > Command window, default <kbd>Alt+Ctrl+A</kbd>), but not all of them are available outside of the Text Editor context, and binding them to keys is perhaps the only way to try them. In addition to assigning a keystroke, placing toggle-style commands on a toolbar is convenient, as it provides an instant feedback of the feature toggle state.

Here's a screenshot with a transcription of all 10 available commands:

```
Edit.Copilot.LearnMore
Edit.Copilot.Open
Edit.Copilot.Settings
Edit.Copilot.SignIn
Edit.Copilot.SignInWithDeviceFlow
Edit.Copilot.SignOut
Edit.Copilot.ToggleGlobally
Edit.Copilot.ToggleLanguage
Edit.Copilot.ToggleSolution
Edit.Copilot.TriggerInlineSuggestion
```

[image: the environment / keyboard section of the main tools / options dialog with the text quote copilot unquote entered into the quote show commands containing unquote text entry field with the shortcut Alt + c, showing a filtered list of the ten commands listed above this image.]